# Contamination issue

Tags: conjunctions

Please consider this sentence:

> *The Test provides insight into how to deal with difficult people, such as [difficult] employees.*

Should the word *difficult* be repeated?

I wonder whether *such as* refers exclusively to *people* or to *difficult people*, because not all the employees are difficult to get along with.

Comment: It is preferable not to repeat words and expressions, particularly in the same sentence. It is sometimes described as *using terms which are redundant*. In your example I might say, for example *troublesome employees*. I do not understand your second question.

Comment: The question title mentions "contamination", which does not appear to have much to do with the question body. Perhaps I've misunderstood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that repeating *difficult* (or using a synonym) before *employees* is needed. Otherwise it is likely that you are communicating a belief that employees generally are difficult people to deal with.

Comment: Thank you. And I also implicitly understood that leaving the comma out doesn’t change the meaning of the sentence.